# TortoiseHG and TortoiseSVN play well together?

Tags: svn, mercurial, tortoisesvn, tortoisehg

I had TSVN installed first and been using for a long time. Then I install T-HG and when I right click I dont see any TortoiseHG.

Does anyone have this same problem?

All the T-SVN overlays are still there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** This information is out of date.

**EDIT:** I think this has to do with me using Windows XP **x64** See [here](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/FAQ#does-tortoisehg-work-on-vista):

Does TortoiseHg work on Vista?

TortoiseHg => 0.4 does work on 32-bit Windows Vista, but there are still problems with 64-bit Vista. Context menus do not work in the 64-bit Windows Explorer. You must use the 32-bit Windows Explorer as described below. The overlays and context menu do work with third-party 32-bit file managers, like FreeCommander or TotalCommander.

Also note that the GTK theme used on Vista had problems on versions before 0.7. In version 0.7, we changed the default theme to one that worked properly on Vista. In 0.7.1, we upgraded GTK so even the old MS-Windows theme should work properly on Vista.
How can I get the context menus working on 64-bit Vista?

The problem is that Windows Explorer is a 64-bit process, and 64-bit processes can not communicate directly with 32-bit libraries. However, fortunately Vista 64 comes with a 32-bit version of Explorer. To start the 32-bit version of Explorer, create a shortcut with the following settings:
Target: %windir%\syswow64\explorer.exe /separate
Start In: %windir%\syswow64\

From this instance of Explorer, you can access the TortoiseHg shell extension.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with version 0.8 (released 2009-07-01) TortoiseHg supports Windows Vista 64bit explorer shell integration. Thanks to the new C++ shell extension (I contributed significantly to that).

Check current release TortoiseHg-0.8.1-hg-1.3.1.exe available from http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/downloads/

Answer (score 3):

On day 1, Yes. TortoiseHG (0.9.3 via the Kiln Client download at FogBugz) and TortoiseSVN (1.6.7, Build 18415 - 64 Bit , 2010/01/22 17:55:06) seem to play together with no issues on Windows 7 x64.

Right-clicking in Explorer gives you both submenus and the overlays seem to work fine for both types of repositories.

I haven't tried too hard to create both types pf repository in the same place but it seems like Subversion won't create one where there is already a Mercurial (Hg) repo. However HG seemed happy to create a repo in the same place as an existing SVN repo. I didn't test too far as to whether both repos synced properly yet so be careful there. Test that one before you use it in anger.

Comment: 6 months later and they still happily co-exist. Now all I need to do is install TortoiseGit and blow the whole thing up.

Comment: Update: TortoiseSVN, TortoiseHg & TortoiseGit all seem happy together in Windows 7 x64 as of the versions current at the time of writing. Git is a bit of a PITA to set up & I only did it because of GitHub. Icon overlays seem ok for everything.

Comment: Ar, I probably don't need TortoiseGit. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573571/cloning-a-read-write-github-repository-using-tortoisehg

Comment: Ditched TortoiseGit. TortoiseHg works fine with GitHub et al.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same problem as you. I have TortoiseSVN installed, and can't get TortoiseHG or TortoiseGit to work. Only TortoiseSVN shows up in the context menus. Running 64-bit Vista.

Comment: Hmm..could this be 64-bit related? I'm running 64-bit Windows XP.

Comment: Just got tortoiseSVN and tortoiseGIT working together on Vista64 -- make sure you install the 64-bit version or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, on one machine (a Windows 2000 box). On my other, XP, machine I have the two living happily together.

The XP machine recently had its overlays disappear when I upgraded T-Svn. I fixed the problem by reinstalling both. Perhaps that's your answer here, to fix your right-click menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had this on my vista and XP, no problem. I even have a folder version controlled by 2 of them, but in case of overlay problem, I write 2 script to make sure only one of them active:

EnableHg.cmd:

```
FOR /R %%f IN (.svn) DO IF EXIST "%%f" 
     ATTRIB -h "%%f"
     RENAME "%%f" 3.svn
     ATTRIB +h "%%f"
)
move 3.hg .hg
```

EnableSVN.cmd:

```
move .hg 3.hg
FOR /R %%f IN (3.svn) DO IF EXIST "%%f" (
     ATTRIB -h "%%f"
     RENAME "%%f" .svn
     ATTRIB +h "%%f"
)
move 3.hg .hg
```

Then, I updated my svn and hg ignore pattern to make sure 2 cmd files are ignored by both and svn ignores *.hg folder, .hgignore file and hg ignores *.svn folder.

Reference: [Re: Command Line Update with TSvn for VS](http://svn.haxx.se/tsvn/archive-2005-11/0126.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a 32-bit version of Explorer in Vista. The T-HG shortcuts will show up when you launch the 32-bit version.

To launch a 32-bit version of Explorer in 64-bit Vista create a shortcut with the target: %Systemroot%\SysWOW64\explorer.exe /separate

When you launch Explorer using the shortcut it should work.