# howto : make Tortoise Hg and Tortoise Svn co-exist

Tags: svn, windows-vista, mercurial, version-control, tortoisesvn

I installed Tortoise Hg(mercurial) on my box. I then installed Tortoise SVN on the same box. When I go to a folder and try the RIGHT MOUSE , I see the menu entries for "Tortoise Hg" and Nothing from "Tortoise SVN".

What gives ?

What can I do to make both co-exist peacefully ? It will be a nice idea if both the teams work together and can come out with a single install for both SCMs.

I'm using Windows Vista Home Premium SP1 64-bit.

Thank you,

Comment: it's vista 64bit related, here's a link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584839/tortoisehg-and-tortoisesvn-play-well-together/2145095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have the 32-bit version of TortoiseSVN installed. Since you're using Vista x64, you have to install the [64-bit version of TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#nomenus).

Answer (score 1):

It works on my machines (x2), both Win 7 x64 using TortoiseHG (0.9.3) and TortoiseSVN (1.6.7, Build 18415 - 64 Bit , 2010/01/22 17:55:06). Reboot? Do you have VisualSVN or AnkhSVN or something else of that nature? Also, TortoiseHG has a taskbar app but I see that's not the one that's letting you down.

I also got the HgSccPackage to work in both VS 2008 & VS 2010RC with no problems. See http://kiln.stackexchange.com/revisions/614/list for details of that.