# Cloning a read-write github repository using TortoiseHg

Tags: git, mercurial, ssh, github, tortoisehg

I'm trying to clone my personal fork on github using the git+ssh protocol with TortoiseHg. It's giving me a rather strange error. Here is the command

```
hg clone git+ssh://git@github.com:myusername/thefork.git
```

This is after I have installed the hg-git module and it works just fine to clone using the git:// syntax. But I believe it's having trouble with the ssh. The error I'm getting is this.

```
importing Hg objects into Git
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have tried adding manually the ssh command into the mercurial.ini file like this

```
[ui]
username = email@address.com
ssh="C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -i "C:\Source\SSHPrivateKey.ppk"
```

But I still get the same error. Any ideas?

**Update 1**

If I run the same command from the Git Bash shell it works just fine. I get this.

```
importing Hg objects into Git
Counting objects: 1559, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (586/586), done.
Total 1559 (delta 960), reused 1534 (delta 947)
importing Git objects into Hg
at:  0/86
updating to branch default
219 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

I'm assuming it's because it can find ssh.exe and my key is already imported. I can add the path of ssh.exe to the windows command prompts path and then instead of the previous error I get this.

```
importing Hg objects into Git
Permission denied (publickey).
abort: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It seems that it's looking specifically for ssh.exe eventhough I have specified the alternate ssh path in mercurial.ini. But my guess here is that that configuration is only for a ssh enabled mercurial server and doesn't apply to the hg-git plugin.

Comment: Note to self - be patient. Once I learned to wait the 5 minutes or so it can take to clone a very large repo, hg-git worked fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a way around this but it's pretty hackish. I noticed that ProcessMonitor was showing it looking for ssh.exe in several different paths so I copied the TortoisePlink.exe in the TortoiseHg folder and named it ssh.exe.

```
copy "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\ssh.exe"
```

With just this change it will still fail the authentication. You'll get a pop-up box and this.

```
importing Hg objects into Git
abort: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So you need to get a hold of [pageant.exe that comes with the main PuTTy install](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). Start that up and add your key to it. Then run the clone command again and it should authenticate just fine.

Comment: The copy step is not necessary on my box. Just install putty-0.60-installer.exe from the link @Nathan provided, and then launch pageant.exe from Start menu. After that you can add your GitHub key to it.

Answer (score 2):

After spending hours and hours trying to solve this, I've found one guide what explained it perfectly.

This is the URL:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376058/Step-by-step-Setup-TortoiseHg-for-gitHub

One thing not mentioned in the guide is that the 32-bit version of Pageant bundled with TortoiseHG cannot recognise the "git@" part in an url, and keeps asking for it. Downloading the 64-bit version of Pageant fixes this bug.

Download 64-bit Pageant:
https://splunk.net/w/PuTTy64bit

I've opened a ticket for including 64-bit Pageant with TortoiseHG:
https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/2145/bundle-64-bit-pageant-with-64-bit

Comment: This appears to be ok with THG v2.5.1. My Pageant is .x64 & I haven't touched it.

Answer (score 1):

I found I had to launch Pageant and load my SSH key and then *initially* clone **using the command-line** e.g.:

```
hg clone git+ssh://git@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
```

But from then on I could use TortoiseHg against GitHub (push and pull) just fine (although Pageant needs to be running for authentication to work).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "plink.exe" and "pageant.exe" instead of "TortoisePlink.exe".  "pageant.exe" provides the pass phrase automatically when "plink.exe" needs it.

Comment: What is the configuration you are using in mercurial.ini? I've tried plink.exe from the regular PuTTY distribution but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by copying TortoisePlink.exe to ssh.exe.  Then I placed ssh.exe in my path.  As long as pageant is running, that works for me.

Given that I needed ssh.exe in my path, I wonder if hggit even reads the ssh= line at all.

This is still hackish, but a little less hackish than @Nathan's technique (I'm not a fan of messing with files inside \Program Files)