# Mercurial Hg-Git: Clone from a local directory?

Tags: git, mercurial, hg-git

I have a local Git repository on my computer that I am trying to clone with [Hg-Git](http://hg-git.github.com/). It works fine for me when I'm cloning from a `git://` type path, but not if I try to clone from local directories.

Here is an example...

```
hg clone "C:\Users\James\Documents\My Games\FalloutNV"
destination directory: FalloutNV
importing Hg objects into Git
abort: The system cannot find the file specified
```

The path does exist, and somehow it knows that it's a Git repo, but it has the direction backwards. It should be importing Git objects into a (new) Hg repo.

Any ideas? I am on Windows, trying to use TortoiseHg but comfortable enough in the command line.

---

## Update

Tonight I discovered that if I rename `FalloutNV` to `FalloutNV.git` ... the clone will magically work from the local disk. Just a pointer that may help!

Comment: Does it work when the source directory contains no whitespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is strange since that error message is usually associated with Hg-Git (the [dulwich](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dulwich) part of it) [not finding your ssh key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573571/cloning-a-read-write-github-repository-using-tortoisehg).

That is why [manojlds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526535/manojlds) suggested cloning using *explicitly* the file protocol (except I would use "`file:///C:/Users/James/Documents/My Games/FalloutNV`" with 3 "`/`" at the beginning instead of two).

The "[A guide to getting the hg-git Mercurial plugin to work on a Windows machine](http://candidcode.com/2010/01/12/a-guide-to-converting-from-mercurial-hg-to-git-on-a-windows-client/)" confirms the ssh issue:

> If you’re getting an error like “`abort: The system cannot find the file specified`”, then `dulwich` cannot find ssh in your `PATH`.
>   You need to make sure to install Cygwin’s OpenSSH and that you can run “`ssh`” from the command line.
>   (and it also recommend you get the latest version of the dulwich library)

---

The OP [jocull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97964/jocull) adds in the comment:

> Fun fact: Tonight I discovered that if I rename "`FalloutNV`" to "**`FalloutNV.git`**" ... the clone will magically work from the local disk.

And that is similar to the [Git protocols page](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html), where every path of a local Git repo ends with `.git`.

Comment: I have an SSH keys generated in the Windows equivalent of `~/James/.ssh` inside `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. Where do they need to be set for Dulwich to pick them up by default? I use OpenSSH when I use Git, mostly because Putty keys are never in the same format as places like GitHub.

Comment: I can confirm that it does seem to work properly from the GitBash. Do I need to do any cloning like this from within Cygwin or something instead of the Windows command line? That is slightly more annoying.

Comment: @jocull: regarding openSSH, I had http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573571/cloning-a-read-write-github-repository-using-tortoisehg with more details

Comment: @jocull: regarding git bash, if you are using msysgit (http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list), no Cygwin should be needed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821372/does-git-on-windows-use-mysys/4821920#4821920 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144082/different-between-msysgit-and-cygwin-git/3144417#3144417